# Only One field shown from SQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress, delphi-6

I have a problem trying to get fields from a SQL statement that retuns 2 fields

If I run the query in phpMyAdmin, it returns all the fields correctly. *That means SQL statement is correct*

If I run the SELECT statment with only one field, it returns correct information. *That means connection is Ok*

```
select p.id_product from ps_product p 
left outer join ps_product_lang l 
on p.id_product = l.id_product 
where p.id_product >= :desde1 and p.id_product <= :hasta1
```

This works

```
select p.id_product, l.id_lang from ps_product p 
left outer join ps_product_lang l 
on p.id_product = l.id_product 
where p.id_product >= :desde1 and p.id_product <= :hasta1
```

This also works, bu returns only one field (id_product). Fields.Count=1 !!!

```
select p.id_product, l.name from ps_product p 
left outer join ps_product_lang l 
on p.id_product = l.id_product 
where p.id_product >= :desde1 and p.id_product <= :hasta1
```

This returns this error message:
**Invalid field size**

Note

```
p.id_product is int(10)
p.id_lang is int(10)
l.name is varchar(128)
```

I use Delphi 6 with the driver dbxopenmysql50.dll that I downloaded from [JustSoftwareSolution](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/delphi/dbexpress_and_mysql_5.html)

I tryed using TSQLConnection, TSLDataSet y TSQLClientDataSet. all three of them return the same error message in the same instruction: *Componente*.Open;

I did a simple program for testing. Here are the main functions I use to connect and to get the information I need.

```pascal
procedure TFMMain.EstableceConexionMySQL;
var
  oIni : TiniFile;
begin
  //Conecto si no está conectada
  with MYSQLConnection do
  begin
     try
        if (not Connected) then
        begin
           oIni := TInifile.Create('G2k2Plus.ini');
           try
              DriverName := 'dbxmysql';
              GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverMYSQL50';
              LibraryName := 'dbxopenmysql50.dll';
              VendorLib := 'libmysql.dll';
              LoginPrompt := False;
              Params.Clear;
              Params.Append('BlobSize=-1');
              Params.Append('ErrorResourceFile=');
              Params.Append('LocaleCode=0000');
              Params.Append('Database=' + oIni.ReadString('TiendaVirtual', 'Database ', ''));
              Params.Append('User_Name=' + oIni.ReadString('TiendaVirtual', 'User_Name ', ''));
              Params.Append('Password=' + oIni.ReadString('TiendaVirtual', 'Password ', ''));
              Params.Append('HostName=' + oIni.ReadString('TiendaVirtual', 'HostName ', ''));
           finally
              oIni.Free;
           end;
           Open;
        end;
     except
        on e: Exception do
        begin
           MOutput.Lines.Add('Error al abrir conexion MySQL');
           MOutput.Lines.Add(e.Message);
        end;
     end;
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
procedure TFMMain.BTraerDatosSQLQueryClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Q : TSQLQuery;
  i : integer;
  Desde, Hasta : integer;
  s : string;
begin
  Desde := 0;
  Hasta := 24;
  BConectar.Click;

     if (MYSQLConnection.Connected) then
     begin
        Q := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
        try
           with Q do
           begin
              try
                 SQLConnection := MYSQLConnection;
                 if (Active) then
                    Close;
                 SQL.Text := 'select p.id_product, l.name from ps_product p ' +
                    'left outer join ps_product_lang l ' +
                    'on p.id_product = l.id_product ' +
                    'where p.id_product >= :desde1 and p.id_product <= :hasta1';
                 //PrepareStatement;
                 Params.FindParam('desde1').Value := Desde;
                 Params.FindParam('hasta1').Value := Hasta;
                 Open; // ERROR HERE !!!
                 MOutput.Lines.Add('Campos: ' + IntToStr(Fields.Count));
                 for i := 0 to Fields.Count -1 do
                 begin
                    MOutput.Lines.Add('   DisplayName '+Fields[i].DisplayName);
                    MOutput.Lines.Add('   FullName '+Fields[i].FullName);
                    MOutput.Lines.Add('   FieldName '+Fields[i].FieldName);
                    MOutput.Lines.Add('   Origin '+Fields[i].Origin);
                 end;
                 MOutput.Lines.Add('-----------');

                 s := '';
                 for i := 0 to Fields.Count -1 do
                    s := s + UpperCase(Fields[i].FieldName)+', ';
                 MOutput.Lines.Add(s);
                 while (not EOF) do
                 begin
                    s := '';
                    for i := 0 to Fields.Count -1 do
                       s := s + Fields[i].AsString+', ';
                    MOutput.Lines.Add(s);
                    Next;
                 end;
                 MOutput.Lines.Add('-----------');
                 Close;
              except
                 on e: Exception do
                 begin
                    MOutput.Lines.Add('-----------');
                    MOutput.Lines.Add('EXCEPTION');
                    MOutput.Lines.Add(e.Message);
                 end;
              end;
           end;
        finally
           Q.Free;
        end;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: In the line where I create the SQL statement SQL.Text := '... I meant to write "... and p.id_product **<=**:hasta1". The formater doesen't allow me to write "<="

Comment: I think this looks like a bug in the driver.

Comment: Or you're using persistent fields on your dataset which do not correspond to the SQL statement anymore after you've changed it. In that case, clear all persistent fields from the dataset and create them again.

Comment: @TOndrej: He uses a brand new TSQLQuery created locally. Probably it is a bug in the driver.

Comment: @Toto You're right, I missed that.

Comment: @Tondrej, @Toto: Do you use another dbExpress driver to connect to MySQL?

Comment: No. Actually I do not use MySQL. I work with Oracle and-or Firebird. But the newer versions of Delphi comes with a MySQL driver in the box.

Comment: @Duilio: I haven't used it yet but I have the default MySQL dbExpress driver which comes installed with Delphi XE.

Comment: use newer version of delphi and dbexpress .new version of mysql has incompatible with old dataprovider.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see to my similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076728/multiple-fields-in-query-dont-work-in-c-builder-6), solution was to change dbExpress Driver for MySQL. Dll **dbxopenmysql50.dll** might work right only with **MySQL v5.0**. In your case DevArt dbExpress Driver for [Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dbx/oracle/) and [Firebird](https://www.devart.com/dbx/interbase/) could be used.