# Multiple fields in query don't work in C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, field, builder

I am using **C++ Builder 6** and I want to query more than one field/column in my query to a table of my MySQL database.

Let's say, I have a table named "users" and my table has the fields "id", "name", "username" and "password". Please, check the following examples:

```
query = "SELECT name FROM users;";  // WORKS

query = "SELECT name, username FROM users;";  // WORKS ONLY FOR THE 1ST FIELD "name"

query = "SELECT * FROM users;";  // DOESN'T WORK: GIVES ME EAccessViolation

query = "SELECT name FROM users UNION SELECT username FROM users;";  // WORKS BUT IT ISN'T A SOLUTION
```

So far, the rest of my code is almost the same I found in this [guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tutorial:_Connecting_to_a_SQLite_Database_from_a_VCL_Application).

**Could I query more than 1 field at the same time?**

***FULL CODE:***

```
String query;

outputMemo->ClearSelection();


// PROBLEMATIC QUERY !!!
query = "SELECT * FROM users;";


try {
  SQLQuery1->SQL->Text = query;
  SQLQuery1->Active = true;
}
catch (Exception& E) {
  outputMemo->Text = "Exception raised with message" + E.Message;
}


// Show the results of the query in a TMemo control.

TStringList *list;
TField      *currentField;
String      currentLine;

if (!SQLQuery1->IsEmpty()) {
  SQLQuery1->First();
  list = new TStringList;
  __try {
    SQLQuery1->GetFieldNames(list);

    while (!SQLQuery1->Eof) {
      currentLine = "";
      for (int i=0; i<list->Count; i++) {
        currentField = SQLQuery1->FieldByName(list->Strings[i]);
        currentLine = currentLine + " " + currentField->AsString;
      }

      outputMemo->Lines->Add( currentLine.c_str() );
      SQLQuery1->Next();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception& E) {
    outputMemo->Text = "Exception raised with message" + E.Message;
  }

  list->Free();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and your time.

Comment: I don't remember a lot of details of C++Builder anymore, but BCB6 is 16 years old and ancient in terms of c++ and modern compilers.  You are going to have difficulty getting any support on something that old.  (And I used to support it.)  Sorry this isn't the news you probably want to hear.

Comment: I know it but I believe I can still use it for many simple applications. However, a solution should exist for this query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was the wrong dbExpress Driver for MySQL. Dll **dbxopenmysql50.dll** might work right only with MySQL v5.0. **DevArt dbExpress Driver for MySQL** could be used for higher versions than v5.0 of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you link to uses *SQLite* and not *MySQL* as in your code.

I am suggesting that the files will be **different** for each DBMS.

Although *MySQL* can be used directly with it's own drivers employing MySQL's api, using *ODBC* with *MySQL* might allow the use of the components.

Comment: Interesting notice. Do you believe that if I use SQLite my problem will be solved? Also, the code seems to work in all parts except the query's part.

Comment: The driver name, files and dlls and need to belong to the same DBMS.

Comment: Library name is: dbxopenmysql50.dll

Comment: VendorLib is: libmysql.dll
I am trying to use MySQL. Is there anything you propose for me to do?

Comment: You have a TSQLConnection control; what is the Driver property value? What is the version number of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL is MySQL Server 5.6 
dbxopenmysql50.dll is from: www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/files/dbxopenmysql5_dll.zip (Guide: http://www.johannesschwichtenberg.de/journal/mysql-mit-c-im-borland-builder-2006-turbo-c.html) (IMAGE: https://prnt.sc/goqkwd)
libmysql.dll is v5.5.39 (IMAGE: https://prnt.sc/goqp6v)
I use these components: (IMAGE: https://prnt.sc/goqgm9)

Comment: If you cannot get the db express dll to work with the newer MySQL server, the MySQL  dll can be used on its own. eg [Using C++ to INSERT INTO MySql Database] (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/118160/)

Comment: Do you suggest to recreate MySQL Database? Because mySql Database has already been filled in with information.

Comment: No, you don't need to recreate the database.

Comment: Could you tell me any steps that might help my situation?

Comment: Thank you DB Baxter for your help and your time so far! I found that the problem was the wrong dbExpress Driver for MySQL. Dll dbxopenmysql50.dll might work right only with MySQL v5.0. DevArt dbExpress Driver for MySQL could be used for higher versions than v5.0 of MySQL.